# Boltzmann sampling for knapsack constraints?

Tags: sampling

Is there an efficient algorithm to sample from the Boltzmann distribution defined by a knapsack constraint? More concretely, I have $n$ items with weights $w_1,...,w_n$ and values $v_1,...,v_n$.
I have a collection of sets $\mathcal{C} \subset 2^{\{1,...,n\}}$ defined by the Kanpsack constraint $S \in \mathcal{C} \iff \sum_{i \in S} w_i \leq \tau$, for some threshold $\tau$. The Boltzmann distribution is given by

$$Pr(S) = \frac{e^{\sum_{i \in S} v_i}}{\sum_{S' \in \mathcal{C}} e^{\sum_{i \in S'} v_i}}.$$

Are there efficient algorithms that can sample from the above distribution? Additionally, given a set $S$, is it possible to approximate $Pr(S)$ efficiently?

I'm aware such algorithms exist for other combinatorial structures (http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/DuFlLoSc04.pdf) but haven't been able to find references for Knapsack structures.